# How to automatically add a newly saved record to the ui-grid?

Tags: angularjs

I am learning angular-js and spring. I have a listing screen where I used the angular ui-grid. From the listing screen, there is a provision to add the new record by clicking a button and through a pop up. Now , when the user added a record through the pop up but its not reflected in the grid even after the record is successfully saved in the database. Can someone guide me to push the record to the grid after the database save?.

#### html for the listing screen

```
<md-card flex >
    <div ui-grid=" vehicleGrid" ui-grid-exporter ui-grid-selection class="myGrid"></div>
</md-card> 

<md-button class="md-fab md-fab-bottom-right md-accent" aria-label="Add Vehicle" ui-sref="vehicle_mgmnt.add">
    <md-icon>add</md-icon>
</md-button>
```

#### Controller - vehicle_mgmnt controller

```
angular.module('trackzApp')
  .controller('VehicleMgmntController', function($scope, $mdDialog, $mdMedia, Principal, Vehicle, ParseLinks, Language, uiGridConstants) {
      //$scope.users = [];
      $scope.authorities = ["ROLE_USER", "ROLE_ADMIN"];
      Language.getAll().then(function(languages) {
        $scope.languages = languages;
      });

      Principal.identity().then(function(account) {
        $scope.currentAccount = account;
      });
      $scope.customFullscreen = $mdMedia('xs') || $mdMedia('sm');
      // $scope.page = 1;
      $scope.vehicleGrid = {
        showGridFooter: true,
        showColumnFooter: true,
        enableFiltering: true,
        exporterMenuCsv: true,
        enableGridMenu: true,
        columnDefs: [{
          field: 'company'
        }, {
          field: 'vehicleCode'
        }, {
          field: 'vehicleName'
        }, {
          field: 'regn_no'
        }, {
          field: 'vehicleType'
        }, {
          field: 'manufacturer'
        }, ],
        onRegisterApi: function(gridApi) {
          $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
        }
      }
      $scope.loadAll = function() {
        Vehicle.query({}, function(result, headers) {
          $scope.links = ParseLinks.parse(headers('link'));
          $scope.totalItems = headers('X-Total-Count');
          // $scope.users = result;
          $scope.vehicleGrid.data = result;
        });

      };

      $scope.loadAll();
    }
```

#### Controller for the pop-up screen.

```
angular.module('trackzApp').controller('VehicleMgmntAddDialogController', ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$mdDialog', '$mdMedia', 'Vehicle', 'Language',
  function($scope, $stateParams, $mdDialog, $mdMedia, Vehicle, Language) {

    // $scope.user = entity;
    $scope.authorities = ["ROLE_USER", "ROLE_ADMIN"];
    Language.getAll().then(function(languages) {
      $scope.languages = languages;
    });
    var onSaveSuccess = function(result) {
      $scope.isSaving = false;
      //$uibModalInstance.close(result);
      $mdDialog.hide();
    };

    var onSaveError = function(result) {
      $scope.isSaving = false;
    };


    $scope.save = function() {
      $scope.isSaving = true;
      /*if ($scope.user.id != null) {
          User.update($scope.user, onSaveSuccess, onSaveError);
      } else {*/
      Vehicle.save($scope.vehicle, onSaveSuccess, onSaveError);
      $scope.$parent.vehicleGrid.push(vehicle);
      // }

    };

    $scope.hide = function() {
      $mdDialog.hide();
    };
    $scope.cancel = function() {
      $mdDialog.cancel();
    };

    $scope.clear = function() {
      // $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };

  }
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

1, I think you have a typo problem:

In your VehicleMgmntController controller the data coming back from the server is stored in:

> $scope.vehicleGrid.data = result;

But in your modal you want to push something in the vehicleGrid which contains the setup data of the grid not the datasource.

```
$scope.save = function() {
      $scope.isSaving = true;
      /*if ($scope.user.id != null) {
          User.update($scope.user, onSaveSuccess, onSaveError);
      } else {*/
      Vehicle.save($scope.vehicle, onSaveSuccess, onSaveError);
      $scope.$parent.vehicleGrid.push(vehicle);
      //try this:
      $scope.$parent.vehicleGrid.data.push(vehicle);          
      // }

    };
```

I think Vehicle service returns with the newly added vehicle, right?

2, I have the feeling, you onSAveSuccess runs later than your Vehicle.save. Have you considered to use the .then() syntax to deal with promises?

```
$scope.save = function() {
      $scope.isSaving = true;
      /*if ($scope.user.id != null) {
          User.update($scope.user, onSaveSuccess, onSaveError);
      } else {*/
      Vehicle.save($scope.vehicle).then(function(result) {
             $scope.$parent.vehicleGrid.data.push(vehicle);
      }, function(error){
            //some error handling
      });

      // }

    };
```

Comment: Thanks SayusiAndo. Seems like its not working. Is there any issue when accessing it using $scope.$parent?.. How can I define the controller of vehicle management screen as parent of pop up screen?